# Can't read pages liked by the user using Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i am new to facebook development on android. My target is to get the list of page names liked by a user. I am using the fallowing code for that.

I want to make sure that i am using the latest facebook sdk and none of the classes or methods i am using are deprecated

```
    ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("user_likes");
    loginButton.clearPermissions();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);
    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if(user != null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"User login successful:"+user.getProperty("favorite_teams"));
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if(session !=null && session.isOpened())
                {
                    if(session.getPermissions().contains("user_likes"))
                    {
                        requestForPageLikes = new Request(session, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes");
                        requestForPageLikes.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                                GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
                                JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
                                Log.d(TAG,"Facebook response:"+jso.toString());

                            }
                        });
                        Request.executeAndWait(requestForPageLikes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above request is working fine and i am getting the response code as 200, which is OK.

but the log message is printing as

Facebook response:{"id":"https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes"}

I am sure that there are pages which the user has liked, and my app is configured well in developers.facebook.com and as we see in the above code i have the permission user_likes which is required to read the like pages.

I am heavily stuck with this issue. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Still waiting for the help from some one.. could any one please respond on this ??

Comment: did you get the solution?